# Prove that $\iint_{\Bbb{R}^2}f(x^3+x,{y\over 3x^2+1})=\iint_{\Bbb{R}^2}f(x,y)$,

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Prove that $\displaystyle \iint_{\Bbb{R}^2} f\left(x^3+x,{y\over 3x^2+1}\right) \, d(x,y) = \iint_{\Bbb{R}^2} f(x,y) \, d(x,y)$ for every continuous $f:\Bbb{R}^2\to \Bbb{R}$ with bounded support.

My initial attempt would be:

$$\iint_{\Bbb{R}^2}f\left(x^3+x,{y\over 3x^2+1}\right) \, d(x,y)=\int_{\Bbb{R}}\left(\int_{\Bbb{R}} f\left(x^3+x,{y\over 3x^2+1}\right)\,dx\right)\,dy = \int_{\Bbb{R}} \left(\int_{\Bbb{R}} f(g(x,y)) \,dx\right)\,dy.$$

I am stuck here because it is taken from notes where Change of Variables has not yet been presented, and it makes me believe this is not the only way to approach it. Do you have any further observation on it? (It works pretty well with Change of Variables.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the fact that
\begin{align*}
   \iint_{\mathbb{R}^2} f(x^3+x,\frac{y}{3x^2+1})d(x,y)
   =
   \int_{\mathbb{R}}\left( \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x^3+x,\frac{y}{3x^2+1})dy \right)dx
\end{align*}
combined with the one-dimensional change of variables formula.

In particular,
\begin{align*}
   \iint_{\mathbb{R}^2} f(x^3+x,\frac{y}{3x^2+1})d(x,y)
   &=
   \int_{\mathbb{R}}\left( \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x^3+x,\frac{y}{3x^2+1})dy\right)dx \\
   &=
   \int_{\mathbb{R}}\left( \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x^3+x,z)(3x^2+1)dz \right)dx \\
   &=
   \int_{\mathbb{R}}\left( \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x^3+x,z)(3x^2+1)dx \right)dz \\
   &=
   \int_{\mathbb{R}}\left( \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(w,z)dw \right)dz \\
   &=
   \iint_{\mathbb{R}^2} f(w,z)d(w,z) \\
\end{align*}

Comment: @AlexM. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To begin, notice that the change of variables $u = x^3 + x, \ v = \frac y {3x^2 + 1}$ is smooth. The Jacobian of the transformation $(x,y) \mapsto (u,v) = F(x,y)$ is

$$\begin{vmatrix} \frac {\partial u} {\partial x} && \frac {\partial u} {\partial y} \\ \frac {\partial v} {\partial x} && \frac {\partial v} {\partial y} \end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix} 3x^2 + 1 && 0 \\ \frac {\partial v} {\partial x} && \frac 1 {3x^2 + 1} \end{vmatrix} = 1 .$$

Next, we need to show that this map is a diffeomorphism of $\Bbb R^2$.

If $F(a,b) = F(x,y)$ then, in particular, $u(a,b) = u(x,y)$, so $a^3 + a = x^3 + x$, or $(a-x) (a^2 + ax + x^2 + 1) = 0$. Notice that the quantity between parantheses is $(a + \frac x 2)^2 + \frac {3 x^2} 4 + 1$ which is *strictly* positive, which forces $x=a$. From $F(a,b) = F(x,y)$ also follows that $v(a,b) = v(x,y)$, and since $x=a$ this implies $y=b$. Thus, $F$ is injective.

If $(X,Y) \in \Bbb R^2$, let's look at the equation $x^3 + x - X = 0$. Since $\lim \limits _{x \to -\infty} x^3 + x - X = -\infty$ and $\lim \limits _{x \to \infty} x^3 + x - X = \infty$, it follows that there exist $x_0$ a root of the above equation. Let then $y_0 = (3x_0 ^2 + 1) Y$. It is easy to check now that $F(x_0, y_0) = (X,Y)$, so $F$ is surjective.

We have just proved that $F$ is bijective and smooth, and that its derivative at every point is non-zero (because it has determinant $1$, see above). $F$ will then have an inverse. By applying [the inverse function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem) around every point, we get that $F$ admits *smooth* inverses *around every point*. Each such local inverse must coincide with $F^{-1}$, because the inverse of a function is unique. Therefore, $F^{-1}$ is smooth around each point. Since a function that is locally smooth is *globally* so (smoothness is a local property), it follows that $F^{-1}$ is smooth, therefore $F$ is a diffeomorphism.

Now we may apply the theorem concerning changes of variables in integrals, to get that

$$\int \limits _{\Bbb R^2} f(x,y) \ \textrm d x \textrm d y = \int \limits _{\Bbb R^2} f(u,v) \ \textrm d u \textrm d v =  \int \limits _{F(\Bbb R^2)} f(u,v) \ \textrm d u \textrm d v = \int \limits _{\Bbb R^2} (f \circ F) (x,y) \underbrace {|\det \ \textrm d F (x,y)|} _{=1} \ \textrm d x \textrm d y = \\
\int \limits _{\Bbb R^2} (f \circ F) (x,y) \ \textrm d x \textrm d y = \int \limits _{\Bbb R^2} f (x^3 + x, \frac y {3x^2 + 1}) \ \textrm d x \textrm d y .$$

Comment: Aaah, sorry, only after posting this did I see that you were asking for a proof not based upon changes of variables. Such a proof might be given by performing two consecutive $1$-dimensional changes of variable. Anyway, I'll let my answer here, I've worked too much on typing it only to delete it now. :)

Comment: That's okay. It shall be of use in the next task.

Comment: I really appreciate the elaborated explanation. It sorted out many things for me.

Comment: Please don't delete it...